# Add python function to c++ program

Tags: python, c++, python-2.7

If I have a program in `c++`, can I add my own function `my_fun()` written in `Python` to this program? Is any simple tutorial how can I do that? I found some suggestions about boost and built-in functions, but I can't find how add my own function

Answer (score 2):

There is information in the Python documentation about embedded Python in C++ programs.
[Here is the Python 2 version of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding) and [here is the Python 3 version](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding)

Without knowing how simple or complex my_fun is - the "very high level embedding" might be sufficient for your needs.